# How to Get Rid of Objective-C In Swift

Tags: swift, xcode

I'm having problems trying to get rid of Objective-C reference in my Swift code. Specifically, if I set the Swift 3 @objc Inference to Default, I get the following runtime error:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[Receiving.TaskViewController numberOfComponentsInPickerView:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
```

My code is simple at that point. It is:

```
func numberOfComponentsInPickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
    return 1
}
```

I'm not sure how to modify my code to stop this error. Or is there some other configuration step I need to do?

Another issue I'm having is with selectors. If I use #selector(method), I have to put @objc in front of the method. What syntax should be used for a selector parameter so the method doesn't have to be exposed to Objective-C?

Comment: It should be `func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int`

Comment: this page answers your question: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/using_objective-c_runtime_features_in_swift